# Docker - Creating directory with PHP outside docker container

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, docker, docker-compose

It's my first question here so hopefully I won't violate any rules :)

I am trying to run a script that creates a sub-directory within /var/www/. I have a script that is supposed to create a directory that is automatically converted to LEMP vHost - it checks /var/www directory for subfolders containing htdocs inside and then generated a virtual host automatically.

LEMP(nginx, PHP 5.6, MySQL) stack is running in docker container on Ubuntu 16.04 Server.

The problem is that I cannot find a way to get proper permission config for this task. My code looks as follows:

```
<?php
if(mkdir("/var/www/".$_POST['name']."/htdocs", 0644, true))
{
    echo('vHost created');
}
else
{
    echo('ERROR!');
}
?>
```

My current permission for /var/www directory are 777(I know it is not really safe approach, but I was desperate). I was trying various permissions and ownership - inside and outside of container, but every time I am calling a PHP file it returns following error.

```
Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in /var/www/default/htdocs/createVhosts.php on line 42
```

Any ideas or suggestions that I should try?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've answered my question myself.

For others who were facing or will face the same issue:
When I've coded it and get an error I was trying to find a cause in permissions, but I didn't realize I was trying to write to host rather than container.

I have solved an issue by replacing:

```
/var/www/
```

with

```
/shared/httpd/
```